# why does wso2 carbon 4.1.0 contains 2 copies of axiom and axis in the source tree?

Tags: wso2

I have checked out wso2carbon 4.1.0 source:

`svn checkout http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0 wso2carbon`

in the `dependencies` folder, there is:

```
axiom\1.2.11-wso2v4
axis\1.6.1-wso2v9
```

and

```
orbit\axiom\1.2.11.wso2v4
orbit\axis2\1.6.1.wso2v9
```

I can see that the first two end with `-wso2v4/9` and the other two end with `.wso2v4/9`

What is the purpose of these different projects with similar names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in the dependencies folder, there is:

axiom\1.2.11-wso2v4
axis\1.6.1-wso2v9
```

It contains axis/axiom source files, which are dependencies.

```
orbit\axiom\1.2.11.wso2v4
orbit\axis2\1.6.1.wso2v9
```

Here we make osgi bundles out of those dependencies. If you check those orbit/..folders only pom file is present.